# django app in heroku getting worker timeout error

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

I have deployed a django app and deployed to Heroku it takes facebook account id's as input through CSV file
and parses information. it works fine in the local server but I am getting the below mentioned error when I try to upload a larger CSV file.

---

```
     14:12:16 web.1  | 2014-07-17 14:12:16 [30747] [INFO] Using worker: sync
     14:12:16 web.1  | 2014-07-17 14:12:16 [30752] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30752
     14:13:21 web.1  | 2014-07-17 14:13:21 [30747] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:30752)
     14:13:21 web.1  | 2014-07-17 03:43:21 [30752] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 30752)
     14:13:21 web.1  | 2014-07-17 14:13:21 [30841] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Heroku [requests are limited to 30 seconds](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout), if the request take longer than this the router will terminate the request

You can increase the [LOG LEVEL of gunicorn](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#loglevel) to see if there's some error in your process

Comment: Heroku's 30sec max cannot be adjusted up: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout.

Comment: @fasouto how to increase log level of gunicorn in windows? Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Example of Procfile with timeout increased to 15 sec

```
web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi --timeout 15 --keep-alive 5 --log-level debug
```

Comment: Heroku's 30sec max cannot be adjusted up: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout.