# Heroku local not working, but works on the production server

Tags: python, django, heroku

I was having some trouble with heroku local, so I went back and tried this with the heroku django starter pack, and got the same results.

When I run heroku local and go to local host:5000, I get a timeout error on the page. However, I push the same code to heroku master and I am able to access the site on the deploy server just fine. I have not touched anything else in the python-getting-started project, and I followed all the steps on the tutorial leading up to heroku local.

When the page finally stops trying to load, this is output in my console:

```
[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid: 22555)
[INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 22555)
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22560
```

I am literally just running off of the basic django python-getting-started project. I have installed all the necessary requirements. This worked the first time I did it yesterday, so I do not know why it is not working now. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Does increasing the worker timeout help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24801323/1757321

Comment: Is something running on port 5000 on your machine already? Try running on another port `heroku local web -p 8000`

Comment: Running heroku local on a different port worked! Which is strange. There were no other processes running on port 5000. However, I had previously killed a running process on it via kill -9 so that may have caused it. Unfortunately, it seems that port 5000 is now unusable...

Answer (score 5):

This is almost certainly because you already have a process using port 5000. The comments suggest you have already solved this, but I figured I'd answer for others and help unblock that port. Assuming you are a *nix machine, you can check if another process is using the 5000 port by typing:

```
lsof -i :5000
```

From there look for the PID number listed in the response and try `kill <the pid>` or even `kill -9 <the pid>`

Sorry, I have no idea how to do this on Windows.