# Error code H13 with Django App deployed on Heroku when trying to access Django page

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, django-admin

My website and admin page work locally, but I am getting an application error:H13 when trying to access my admin page on the Heroku web page.

Here is a portion of the heroku logs:

```
[web.1]: 10.47.180.171 - - [29/Feb/2020:21:10:30 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://quiet-woodland-94985.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36"
2020-02-29T21:18:46.170318+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-29 21:18:46 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
2020-02-29T21:18:46.166523+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/admin/" host=quiet-woodland-94985.herokuapp.com request_id=43137702-84dc-4892-b3bf-9c0c6d155a6b fwd="174.55.195.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=67ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-02-29T21:18:56.996229+00:00 app[api]: Set DJANGO_ADMIN_URL config vars by user phikhant@uci.edu
2020-02-29T21:18:56.996229+00:00 app[api]: Release v22 created by user phikhant@uci.edu
2020-02-29T21:18:57.341490+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-02-29T21:18:57.344662+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-02-29T21:18:58.324719+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-29 21:18:58 +0000] [13] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13)[2020-02-29 21:18:58 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
2020-02-29T21:18:58.324729+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-02-29T21:18:58.324730+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-29 21:18:58 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2020-02-29T21:18:58.420449+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-29 21:18:58 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-02-29T21:18:58.304389+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-02-29T21:18:58.508719+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-02-29T21:19:01.612316+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn TreatmentPlanning.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-02-29T21:19:03.436411+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-29 21:19:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-02-29T21:19:03.436964+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-29 21:19:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:59479 (4)
2020-02-29T21:19:03.437062+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-29 21:19:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-02-29T21:19:03.441089+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-29 21:19:03 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-02-29T21:19:03.500564+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-29 21:19:03 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-02-29T21:19:03.877103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-02-29T21:19:06.855573+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-29 21:19:06 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
2020-02-29T21:19:06.852571+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/admin/" host=quiet-woodland-94985.herokuapp.com request_id=ba1359d8-8365-4e35-bc10-93f902e33ee5 fwd="174.55.195.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=117ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-02-29T21:21:16.208007+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by user phikhant@uci.edu
2020-02-29T21:21:22.007938+00:00 heroku[run.3168]: State changed from starting to up
2020-02-29T21:21:22.178709+00:00 heroku[run.3168]: Awaiting client
2020-02-29T21:21:22.214591+00:00 heroku[run.3168]: Starting process with command `bash`
2020-02-29T21:21:58.055564+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/admin/" host=quiet-woodland-94985.herokuapp.com request_id=b67d0ddd-d88d-4c39-9cca-15c27ea7cc16 fwd="174.55.195.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=106ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-02-29T21:21:58.058202+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-29 21:21:58 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
2020-02-29T21:22:00.518484+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=quiet-woodland-94985.herokuapp.com request_id=b8f0acaf-c2f4-4260-82cf-5f900673d1c7 fwd="174.55.195.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=63ms status=200 bytes=4899 protocol=https
2020-02-29T21:22:00.511031+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.30.127.176 - - [29/Feb/2020:21:22:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4681 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36"
2020-02-29T21:22:02.627781+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/admin/" host=quiet-woodland-94985.herokuapp.com request_id=f722da7b-00d9-46e7-9e78-20d1e098d11c fwd="174.55.195.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=95ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-02-29T21:22:02.631308+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-29 21:22:02 +0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14
2020-02-29T21:22:04.932431+00:00 heroku[run.3168]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2020-02-29T21:22:05.499704+00:00 heroku[run.3168]: State changed from up to complete
2020-02-29T21:22:05.483859+00:00 heroku[run.3168]: Process exited with status 129
```

Here is my `requirements.txt` file:

```
asgiref==3.2.3
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.3
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
psycopg2==2.8.4
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.0
whitenoise==5.0.1
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
```

And here is my procfile

```
web: gunicorn TreatmentPlanning.wsgi --log-file -
```

EDIT:

While poking around, I found out this application error only shows up after logging in. The django admin landing page still functions properly.

Settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for TreatmentPlanning project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['DJANGO_SECRET_KEY']


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
# DEBUG = True
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', '') != 'False'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['quiet-woodland-94985.herokuapp.com' , '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'treatment_plan.apps.TreatmentPlanConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'TreatmentPlanning.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'TreatmentPlanning.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Heroku: Update database configuration from $DATABASE_URL.
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

# The absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect static files for deployment.
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# The URL to use when referring to static files (where they will be served from)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

url.py in project folder

```
"""TreatmentPlanning URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("treatment_plan.urls")),
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into the same problem while trying to deploy an app created by following the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django). Was able to resolve it by lowering the Django version to 2.2.10. Here is the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/Balavarun5/web-app-deploy/blob/master/requirements.txt) file and the [deployed app](https://calm-temple-23148.herokuapp.com/catalog/books/) is working as it was locally. If you aren't using Django 3 specifically for a purpose then it should be okay to lower it to 2.2.10. The tutorial on MDN was also made using django 2.

Answer (score 1):

Also had this error. Not due to a timeout as it appears instantly. I'd just made changes to requirements.txt, including updating the versions of some of the packages. As I'm on Github, I rolled back the requirements.txt file to a previous version, which fixed the issue. My guess is that your requirements file is causing the issue (although it's difficult to isolate the specific line in it from the error).

Comment: Hi Oliver, I went and updated all of my requirements, made a new requirements.txt file, and pushed it onto Heroku. Still no luck, unfortunately. I have been able to slightly pinpoint the issue more. The default landing page after logging in as an admin does not work and creates an application error. Manually navigating to certain tables such as by going to the URL {site_url}/admin/{app_name}/{model_name} DOES work. This is how I am able to temporarily circumvent this problem, but I still would like a more permanent fix. Could it possibly be due to the landing page having certain static files?

Comment: Going to {site_url}/admin/{app_name} does NOT work either like {site_url}/admin after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this error has to do with a timeout.
This explanation was quoted in the heroku page for H13 error.
"One example where this might happen is when a Unicorn web server is configured with a timeout shorter than 30s and a request has not been processed by a worker before the timeout happens. In this case, Unicorn closes the connection before any data is written, resulting in an H13."

So i think that this response can help you out with your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28336729/7938870

Comment: I took a look and adjusted my procfile but still no luck.  I'm not sure I fully understand the error because it is definitely not taking 30 seconds for the application error to appear, it happens nearly instantaneously.

Comment: Yep, same probleme over here. Tried the suggested trick but still not working.