# Gunicorn settings don't work in production

Tags: flask, heroku, timeout, gunicorn, procfile

I have a Flask app deployed on Heroku using Gunicorn.  Some processes take longer than the default 30 seconds, so I need to make use of the --timeout setting.

When I run `gunicorn --workers=4 --timeout=300 app:app` on my computer, there's no problem.  But when I deploy it on Heroku with a Procfile consisting of `web: gunicorn --workers=4 --timeout=300 app:app` the app works fine but the timeout still defaults to 30 seconds.

When I check the Heroku logs, this is the error message I get after 30 seconds.  Note the 503 status.

`2021-01-15T01:57:01.545230+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api" host=counterpoint-server.herokuapp.com request_id=0865b365-e8de-48f1-bf94-6325206ec7df fwd="73.165.51.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https`

Any idea why my Gunicorn settings are being ignored in production?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django app in heroku getting worker timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799347/django-app-in-heroku-getting-worker-timeout-error)

Comment: Yes it does!  Thanks – it looks like the problem is with heroku, not gunicorn